# Which conditions on $h$ guarantee that $\lim_{a\to0^+}\int_0^1 h(x) a^x dx =0?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

I am joining an advanced calculus I course since I was particularly impressed by the calculus I course (I am bachelor physics student).

I am done with my homework for next week, except for one exercise that I just can not solve. The exercise says: let $h\in C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ and $a>0$. Which conditions on the function $h$ guarantee that
$$\int_0^1 h(x) a^x dx =0 \quad\text{ as } a\to 0?$$

I think that the exercise means to find suitable assumptions on $h$ in such a way that
the limit as $a\to 0$ of that integral is equal to $0$.

Now, I think that the required condition is satisfied when $h$ is a constant function (I have checked it on my own). On the other hand, I can not find any more case in which that condition is satisfied.
I have asked the lecturer for a hint, but he only said that there are more situation in which that condition is satisfied.

Can someone please help in finding them out?

Comment: $\int_0^1 h(x) a^x dx =0 \quad\text{ as } a\to 0$ has no meaning in Advanced Calculus. Also, '$h\in C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ and $a>0$ be fixed' sounds strange

Comment: DCT guarantees that the limit of the  integral is $0$ for any continuous function $h$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: About geetha's first comment: so, you were right to replace it with "the limit as $a\to 0$ of that integral" (but write "is equal to $0$", not "converges to $0$"; alternatively, if you want to write "converges to", suppress "the limit").

Comment: No need of DCT. Since $h$ is bounded, you can very easily derive the general case from the constant case which you already checked.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have edited the question according to them. @AnneBauval could you please give more details? Thanks.

Comment: Also, @geetha290krm, could you please explain how to use DCT here? Thanks.

Comment: Since $h$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, $M:=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|h(x)|<\infty.$ Then, $\left|\int_0^1h(x)a^xdx\right|\le\int_0^1Ma^xdx$ and you already proved that the latter tends to $0$ with $a.$

Comment: Thanks @AnneBauval!

Comment: And what happens if $h\in L^1$ instead? Does DCT apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $h$ is continuous on $[0,1]$,
$$M:=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|h(x)|<\infty.$$
Then,
$$\left|\int_0^1h(x)a^xdx\right|\le\int_0^1Ma^xdx$$
and you already proved that the latter tends to $0$ with $a.$

Edit, upon OP's request: the result still holds when $h$ is only in $L^1$ instead, by DCT, since $\forall x>0,$ $a^x\le1$ as soon as $a\le1,$ and $a^x\to0$ as $a\to0^+.$

Comment: Anne Bauval, may I ask what happens if $h$ is only in $L^1$ instead? Does DCT apply?

Answer (score 2):

*Any* function $h\in C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ satisfies that condition. Since $h$ is continuous, it is bounded by some $M>0$ on $[0,1]$. It follows that

$$\left\lvert\int_0^1h(x)a^x~\mathrm{d}x\right\rvert\leq M\int_0^1a^x~\mathrm{d}x=M\frac{a-1}{\ln a}\to0$$

as $a\downarrow0$.